# How to allow users to customize the app name and icon in a Flutter app?

Tags: android, flutter, mobile

I'm building a Flutter app, and I'd like to provide users with the option to customize the app's name and icon. How can I implement this feature while following best practices? I want users to be able to change the app name and choose their own app icon. Any guidance or code examples would be appreciated.

I've been working on implementing a feature that allows users to customize the app name and icon in my Flutter app. So far, I've tried a few approaches like using packages such as 'flutter_launcher_icons' for the app icon, but I'm not sure how to proceed with changing the app name dynamically.

I was expecting to find a solution that would let users change both the app name and icon within the app itself, allowing for a personalized experience. Can anyone provide some guidance or code examples on how to achieve this in a Flutter app while following best practices?